# Why is gauss law valid for open surface?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

I recently came across this question:-

A point charge +10 μC is a distance 5 cm directly above the centre of a square of side 10 cm, as shown in Fig. 1.34. What is the magnitude of the electric flux through the square?
[image]

Now this surface appears as an open surface so obviously the flux should be zero.
**But** that is not the case. In the solution this question was solved using gauss law and symmetry. By considering the square as one side of a cube we calculated the electric flux.
This doesn't make any sense to me. If we can use this method of **imagining** something which is not there. Then why don't we use it in other problems when the charge is outside a closed surface and the flux is zero . Why doesn't this method work that time.
(Also can we calculate the flux through the method of integration?)

Comment: *Now this surface appears as an open surface so obviously the flux should be zero.* That’s not true. Do you understand how flux is defined?

Comment: Yes I do understand flux. My problem is with gauss law and the methodology used to calculate flux. We know that we take area vector of a closed surface outside the surface and ignore the one inside. But what about this surface. If it's a closed surface we know that if a charge is placed outside a closed surface the no. of electric field lines entering the surface is equal to the no. of field lines exiting the surface

Comment: If you understand flux, you cannot think that the flux through an open surface must be zero, and think that this is obvious.

Comment: I think maybe I worded my question incorrectly. What if we assume the square to be a closed surface

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. Squares are not closed surfaces.

Comment: Think of a thick metal sheet. Is it not a closed surface?

Comment: That is not what this problem means. No thickness is given. It is not a closed surface.

Comment: What? Are we then considering this square as a 1-D object with no thickness

Comment: It is a 2D surface with no thickness. The flux is the surface integral of the field passing through it,  $\int \vec E\cdot d\vec A$. Compute it.

Comment: Okaay but what if the square actually had some thickness? What would happen then? Will the flux be zero?

Comment: Yes, by Gauss’ Law.

Comment: So we can use integration instead of gauss law for calculating the flux?

Comment: Gauss’ Law does not apply to open surfaces. Integrate!

Comment: That's where you are wrong. It does apply in this situation according to my textbook solution

Comment: If you want to use Gauss’ Law, the surface is an imaginary one.

Comment: https://byjus.com/question-answer/a-point-charge-10-mc-is-a-distance-5-cm-directly-above-the-centre-of-1/

Comment: That’s a trick which only applies because of the exact geometry here. (If you made five other sides, the charge would be at the center of a closed cube.) The integral always works.

Comment: And we are back to square one. If gauss law isn't applicable to open surfaces why can't we just image those open surfaces as a part of some imaginary closed surface?

Comment: You can when there is sufficient symmetry. Sorry, this has become too long a discussion

Comment: Or as a matter of fact can't we assume let's say a thick metal sheet as a part of a closed surface say we have a thick square sheet as part of a cube. Then we can calculate flux through this surface but we know that flux would be zero because the charge is outside that closed surface

Answer (score 1):

Gauss' law and flux are not the same thing.

Gauss' law for electric charge says that the total flux through a closed surface is proportional to the electric charge enclosed.

Any defined area can have flux through it. If a field strength 5 is going directly through an area of units 4, the resulting flux would be 20 (units of field strength * area).

Here you use Gauss' law to determine what the total flux would be through a cube, then use symmetry arguments to determine what fraction of that flux must go through each of the sides.

Comment: When I first learned flux I was introduced to two surfaces 1) open surface. 2) closed surface and by conventional we take the area vector of a closed surface outside the surface but what about this surface? It appears as an open surface because it's area vector can emerge from both sides. ( I can rephrase it if it isn't clear)

Comment: It seems the square is a conductor, so al field lines are perpendicular to it, thats why you can assume to have a negative charge on the other side in the same distance, the flux than goes from + to -

Comment: @Andrew for an open surface you can choose either for the area vector. If you choose the opposite one as someone else, you'll just differ by a negative sign.

Comment: But what if this square was a closed 3D surface. Would the flux be zero then?

Comment: I had one more question. How can I solve this problem using integration? My textbook only uses gauss law and symmetry to solve this problem

Comment: @Andrew a square is a 2D object.

Comment: @Andrew You can integrate the normal component of the electric field at surface of the square. It's a 2d integral, and dotted with the normal vector.

Comment: Ok i understand that but what if say this square was not a square but a cuboid and assume this cuboid to be a part of a gaussian surface. We can calculate the flux using gauss law but as we know flux should be zero as the charge is outside the surface. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: @Andrew then you have 6 sides to add together instead of just 1. they'll add up to 0. Really the two adjacent sides cancel out if you make sure the area vector always points out of the closed surface as instructed.

Comment: Okay I think I understand it all now. Thanks for your reply and being patient with me this far.